# URLRequest with DELETE method

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, urlrequest

Need to find a way to send a delete method from Flash Player (Flex). Currently it's not done by default (except for from AIR), but I am sure someone has augmented the URLRequestHeader to get it to work properly.

I've tried this, it isn't working:

```
request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", 
     DELETE_REQUEST_METHOD)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to limitations in NPAPI this is not currently possible.  The only work-around in Flash Player is to use the [as3httpclientlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/) that builds a new HTTP client through Socket instead of through the browser networking API.

Comment: I was afraid you/someone would say that. I've looked at that library and it takes quite a bit to set up (and he is obviously having naming issues with his events). I was just wanting something more transparent. Guess I will have to go whole-hog on this one.

Comment: Actually another option is to proxy the requests through the BlazeDS http proxy service.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for HTTPService say it supports the value "DELETE" for it's "method" property.

Comment: It is supported for AIR, not for Flash Player (web) environments.

Comment: Its possible if you have a socket policy file server. See: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html